# Display custom form mode in twig with drupal_entity_form

Tags: 8

I am using the [form_mode_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager) module for creating new form modes.

I have currently a new edit form mode which is called applicant, but whenever I add the drupal_entity_form function in my twig template, it says:

The "node" entity type did not specify a "applicant" form class.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom module

Let say you call it `module_name`

In your `module_name.module` file you'll have to use the `hook_entity_type_build()`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_build().
 */
function module_name_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->setFormClass('applicant', 'Drupal\node\NodeForm');
}
```

Then enable your `module_name` module and flush the cache.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this solved the problem :)